# Cannot get image from ipfs in vuejs

Tags: ipfs

I want to get an image from IPFS into my Vue/Nuxt project. I already import ipfs by 'npm i ipfs'. But when i run "cont node = Ipfs.create()". it show error [image]
but this error doesn't always happen, many times it works and I can get the image normally. Has anyone ever encountered this situation and have a solution?

```
async downloadImg () {
  const node = await Ipfs.create()
  const { agentVersion, id } = await node.id()
  this.agentVersion = agentVersion
  this.id = id
  const cid = '/ipfs/QmY2dod6X7GFmqnQ6qCBiaeNxJWa3CYQaxEjGUfL5CqMAj'
  // load the raw data from js-ipfs (>=0.40.0)
  const bufs = []
  const a = node.cat(cid)
  for await (const buf of node.cat(cid)) {
    bufs.push(buf)
  }
  const data = Buffer.concat(bufs)
  const blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'image/jpg' })
  this.imageSrc = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
},
```

Answer (score 0):

If am I true it can depends on the web protocol which you use, if you use https its work and in other protocol not !

Comment: it is IPFS. But sometimes it works, sometimes not. I am very confused

Answer (score 0):

The web crypto API is only available on pages accessed via `https`.  If you're seeing that message, you are probably accessing the page via plain `http`.

Follow the github link at the top of the stack trace for more explanation and solutions.